# Encoding using ffmpeg library fails

Tags: encoding, ffmpeg

I've spent some time looking at the ffmpeg library and setting things up, I'm opening a .flv file. Reading and decoding and the frames, now I'm trying to encode it to MP4 but my packets end up empty.

My code as follows

```
int main (){

    avformat_open_input(&pFC, "c://wav//test2.flv", NULL, NULL);

    po = av_find_stream_info(pFC);

    //ADD LOGIC TO FIND VIDEO STREAM
    pCodecC = pFC->streams[0]->codec;

    decoder = avcodec_find_decoder(pCodecC->codec_id);
    encoder = avcodec_find_encoder(pCodecC->codec_id);
    po = avcodec_open(pCodecC, decoder);

    pCodecE =  avcodec_alloc_context3(encoder);
    /* put sample parameters */
    pCodecE->bit_rate = 400000;
    /* resolution must be a multiple of two */
    pCodecE->width = 352;
    pCodecE->height = 288;
    /* frames per second */
    pCodecE->time_base.den = 25;
    pCodecE->time_base.num = 1;
    pCodecE->gop_size = 10; /* emit one intra frame every ten frames */
    pCodecE->max_b_frames=1;
    pCodecE->pix_fmt = PIX_FMT_YUV420P;

    if(pCodecC->codec_id == CODEC_ID_H264)
        av_opt_set(pCodecE->priv_data, "preset", "slow", 0);

    po =  avcodec_open2(pCodecE, encoder, NULL);

    AVFrame *pFrame;
    // Allocate an AVFrame structure



    // Allocate video frame
    pFrame=avcodec_alloc_frame();
    int frameFinished = 0;
    int frame = 0;
    int gotpacket = 0;

    while(av_read_frame(pFC, &packet) >= 0)
    {
        if(packet.stream_index==0) //the video stream is 0
        {
            int len = avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecC, pFrame, &frameFinished, &packet);
            if(frameFinished)
            {
                printf("frame # %i", frame);

                po =avcodec_encode_video2(pCodecE, &spacket, pFrame, &gotpacket);
                if(gotpacket)
                {
                    printf("packet recieved");
                }
                frame++;
            }
        }
        av_free_packet(&packet);
    }


    printf("encoding done");

    return 0;
}
```

Basically everything works up to

```
 po =avcodec_encode_video2(pCodecE, &spacket, pFrame, &gotpacket);
```

Where `&gotpacket` returns 0, as in an empty frame.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation says. The frames might be buffered internally. In this case you would have `gotpacket == 0`. When you continue writing images you will at some point have `gotpacket != 0`

I guess you could also try to flush the encoder by passing NULL for the frame. I haven't tried this thought.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that incrementing the pts in pFrame (after each encode) fixes this issue.

```
pFrame->pts += av_rescale_q(1, video_st->codec->time_base, video_st->time_base);
```

Where video_st is the output stream.